# Swiper slider pagination Bullet Render on hover

Tags: swiper.js

Below is my swiper slider initialization script.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        effect: 'fade',
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,

        spaceBetween: 0,
        height:490,
        loop: true,
        arrows:false,
        autoplay: 4500,
        autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
        paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
            var slide = $('.' + this.wrapperClass).find('.headermainslider')[index];
            return '<span class="' + className + '"><a href="'+$(slide).attr('data-rel')+'" >' + $(slide).attr('data-value') + '</a></span>';
        }
});
```

Each pagination bullet i have create a div and inside div anchor link is place. When i click on bullet slider will change but anchor link not works. 
Due to `paginationonClickable` when I click on anchor link inside bullet div than anchor link not work and current slide change.

I want both condition to work. So can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: I think I have the same issue with pagination clicking, although my code is different to yours, check out my question, I may get an answer quicker seeing as I've posted all my code.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463206/custom-pagination-swiper-js